# Query works wrong MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need you help with SQL query. I need to select all `payments` that have ALL devices ONLY from the query.
For this I do following query:

```
SELECT payments.offer_id
FROM payments
WHERE payments.device IN ('TABLET','DESKTOP','MOBILE','IPOD')
GROUP BY payments.offer_id
HAVING COUNT(payments.id) = '4';
```

Result:

[image]

But result is wrong because if execute following query I see that `payments` for this offerId have only 2 unique devices, it is MOBILE and TABLET.

```
SELECT id, offer_id, device FROM payments WHERE offer_id = 77;
```

[image]

Can you help me and how need to change query for the right result?
Thanks.

Comment: You have GROUPed by `payment.offer_id` so of course you only get one row returned. Remove the `GROUP BY` and see if that is what you want

Comment: @RiggsFolly, `HAVING` don't work without `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT p.offer_id
FROM payments p
WHERE p.device IN ('TABLET', 'DESKTOP', 'MOBILE', 'IPOD')
GROUP BY p.offer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.device) = 4;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Do not put numeric constants in single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- You want to count the distinct number of devices, so you have to count the right column.